# Vkontakte Like Button Does Not Show in FireFox

Tags: vk

I have an issue where I have a hidden toolbar the drops down with social buttons on it, the VK.com like button being one of them.

It refuses to show itself in FireFox. All other browsers work fine however when the bar pulls down there is nothing there in FF. Does Vkontakte have a force load / render like Facebook and Google do where you can programmatically trigger the render of the like button.

Comment: Have  you ever found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have launched video on vkontakte with firefox zoom something other than 1:1. This may result in distorted video player pop-up window size. it is a bitch to fix, since reinstalling firefox and flash player don't do any good.

Launching vk.com videos with different zoom rates, and finally 1:1, seems to fix it.

This may be unrelated to your problem.